# Why does Windows XP boots so slowly?

Tags: windows-xp, performance

My system takes too much time to boot and even once it starts, it's not allowing any thing to do - not even responding to clicking the start button.

I don't want to reinstall Windows again. Any suggestion?

Comment: Give me your `ntbtlog.txt` File. On how to create it http://www.windowsreference.com/general/how-to-create-a-bootlog-in-windows-2000xp-and-later/

Comment: There are a million things that could cause this, but one of the worst slowdowns/most frequent causes I see is a bad hard drive. Make sure your CHKDSK doesn't find any bad blocks. If you have a spare hard drive lying around, try using it and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: @AkshatMittal: I can't even use Start + Run

Comment: @ZacB Says the Truth.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma Dosen't the PC boots UP. Is it just slow of something else.

Comment: so, how to CHKDSK when I can't even click on start button.?

Comment: after slow boot, nothing works. it's too slow to open any single task.

Comment: Then there is some serious Problem, maybe a virus. Also how are you then answering our questions. If you are not on that PC then run a virus scan on it. http://download.bitdefender.com/rescue_cd/BitDefenderRescueCD_v2.0.0_5_10_2010.iso <- Download, Burn to Disk, Boot, Run the Scan, Tell us the Results. I have more suggestions to go, but First this one only.

Comment: yes. I'm on other PC.

Comment: Run the scan then.

Comment: At boot, just after you see your BIOS splash screen go away, you could tap F8 repeatedly to bring up the Safe Mode menu, and then either choose Safe Mode and run CHKDSK from there once it loads, or you could choose Safe Mode with Command Prompt, and run it from the command line.  You do not have to wait until Windows XP loads normally.  This is what Safe Mode is for... repairing issues like this.

Comment: Sounds like the CPU is overheating, most CPU's throttle down when they're hot.  They run, but slooow. (yeah, THAT slow!)

Answer (score 4):

*-Posting as answer since comments have limited characters-*

**We need a lot more info:**

- Computer specs
- current AV
- When this started happening
- what happened right before that point
- last time you did a backup

**We also need to know what you have tried (if anything)**

- Safe Mode?  Mash F8 while starting the computer, and select Safe Mode. I personally choose Safe Mode with Networking to give me internet access while using that mode, but this won't work for people who use a wireless connection.
- Clearing startup items?
- Checking the hard drive and memory using diagnostic tools that run outside of windows (Drive fitness test is one that I like, also SeaTools is not bad.  For memory, memtestx86)?  You could use tool discs like [The Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/), etc.

Once we get the above info, we can start the troubleshooting process, and hopefully narrow down what is happening.